# Push only seems to work on Android with "debuggable true" set, regardless certificate

Tags: android, azure, debugging, android-gradle-plugin, push

I integrated Azure push notification hub in an Android app, and it worked fine for debug builds, but not production builds.

This is not a certificate problem, and I managed to narrow it down to following:

-If "debuggable true" is set in gradle, push works (arrives in app)

-If "debuggable false" is set in gradle, push does not work (does not arrive in app)

I went through the app to ensure BuildConfig.DEBUG wasn't blocking anything.

In what way can "debuggable" influence the functionality of push?
Any input on how I can debug this is highly appreciated!

Comment: Any issue information, like error messages? Maybe the SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363994/android-debuggable-false-causing-jquery-ajax-post-to-fail-in-cordova-phonegap-ec helps for you.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I managed to do a workaround. I'll update the question shortly. Thanks for your suggestion though, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround.

The error is located to the NotificationHandler within the Azure plugin. If *debuggable* is *false*, it fails to deliver the notifications, if *true* it works.

Creating a broadcast receiver and listening for the notifications directly doesn't show this problem.

Still I have no idea how debuggable can influence the Azure plugin though, but issue is avoided for now.

So, solution here is not to use the Azure plugin for receiving the notifications.